# Windows Explorer on taskbar not working

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, taskbar

The shortcut for Windows Explorer on the taskbar has seemingly broken. It shows the default icon and when I click it, I get the following message,

> "Can't open this item. It might have been moved, renamed, or deleted. Do you want to remove this item?"

If I right click the taskbar item, I get all the folders that are usually there, but can't access the default Windows Explorer. The target for the shortcut is

> %windir%\explorer.exe

I have tried restarting, but it doesn't do any good.

Comment: If you try and run `%windir%\explorer.exe` directly from the Run prompt, does Explorer open?  Does it work in Safe Mode? Does `%windir%\explorer.exe` actually exist on your system? Have you done any virus scans yet? How about running SFC to repair missing system files (like Explorer)?  How about disk checks to ensure there's no file system corruption?

Comment: running %windir%\explorer.exe from the Run prompt works. And explorer.exe is in C:\Windows. Going to run a virus scan tonight.

Comment: What do the "Target location" and "Start in" fields say?  What happens if you just kill the pinned shortcut, open Explorer and re-pin it?

Comment: I've run into this, but system apps such as Notepad and Calculator won't run from the start menu either; and they typically are missing the icon as well. I believe it goes back to a super long and/or erroneous 'Path' environment variable.

Comment: OK, so I got it fixed, all except the icon is still wrong. Apparently my PATH was too long, as @panhandel suggested. So I went in and removed about 10 entries that were either unneeded or no longer installed, and it seems to work, at least for now. Thanks for all your help everyone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've run into this, but system apps such as Notepad and Calculator won't run from the start menu either; and they typically are missing the icon as well. I believe it goes back to a super long and/or erroneous 'Path' environment variable.  Since the path variable varies per machine, it would be hard to suggest what to remove, if anything, but you might look there to see if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Per the suggestion of @panhandel, I shortened my PATH environmental variable and it seems to have fixed the issue, all but the missing icon, which I can live with.

Comment: You can probably force a rebuild of your icon cache (involves deleting a file I can't recall the name of) to fix that part, or just wait until you install/uninstall another program, and that usually refreshes it and the icons come back.

Comment: @panhandel please add your suggestion as an answer. Then mark answer as accepted

Comment: @Rudolph I meant to delete the answer suggestion only, forgot that it would delete the comments. DOH!!!

Answer (score 1):

I run Windows 7. The Windows Explorer icon in my task bar quit working. When I tried to open it I got a message stating:

> Can't open this item. It might have been moved, renamed, or deleted.
>
> Do you want to remove this item?

Tried opening in Safe Mode as well but got same message. I ran the SFC scan for corrupted files but the results said none were found so I deleted the icon in the task bar per the message.

I then typed `%windir%\explorer.exe` in the run prompt box. When the Windows Explorer file name came up in the result box I dragged the file name into the task bar and the Windows Explorer folder reappeared and now works properly.

It took me less time to fix it than it did to type this message.